# How to set selected item when looping through php array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an html dropdown box. Then I use an array to fill the items in it. 
The keys in this for each loop is just a number from 0 - 9. My problem now is how can I control what shows up as the default choice:

```
<?php foreach($cat_r as $k=>$c){ ?>
<option name="<?php echo $k + 1; ?>" value="<?php echo $k + 1; ?>" selected="<?php if($k==1){ echo "selected"; } ?>"><?php echo $k + 1; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

In this code, you can see that I'm attempting to make the 2nd item as the default choice.
But it seems like I'm always brought to the last array item whatever number I type as the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php foreach($cat_r as $k=>$c){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $k + 1; ?>" <?php if($k==1){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $k + 1; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

Or, this format works too

```
<option value="foo" selected />
```

Comment: `selected="yes"` is something you made up. That attribute has no value per definition, and if XML compliance is your goal the recommended way is to use `selected="selected"`.

Comment: And that's what I get for answering questions at 1am, that was bad. Thanks for the correction.  Fixed it so there's no misinformation out there.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php foreach($cat_r as $k=>$c){ ?>
    <option name="<?php echo $k + 1; ?>" value="<?php echo $k + 1; ?>" 
    <?php if($k==1){ echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>
    <?php echo $k + 1; ?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came here for finding solution to set options selected by user before as selected , above question was in different context and I ended up in scratching my head to this thing...

```
foreach($options as $k){
   echo "<option value=".$k." ";
   foreach($selectedoptions as $m){
     if($k==$m)
        echo "selected='selected'";
   }

   echo ">".$k."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code was functional for me, thanks..

```
foreach($options as $k){
   echo "<option value=".$k." ";
   foreach($selectedoptions as $m){
     if($k==$m)
        echo "selected='selected'";
   }

   echo ">".$k."</option>";
}
```